# Android Emulator does not keep state on MacOS Big Sur M1

Tags: android, android-emulator, apple-m1

Recently I use Mac M1. The problem is that the Emulator on Android Studio always does not keep state, even thought I setup the `Boot option` to **Quick boot**.

When I close Emulator, it always display this dialog. I selected `Yes`, but it's still same as init state when re-open again.

[image]

*Note: This issue does not happen on Mac Intel chip I used before*

Do you guys have any solution for this?